# Is it possible to break a child stream from it's parent stream and link it to another integration stream?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I would like to link the child stream of an integration stream to another integration stream?
Is there any possible way to do this?

For eg.

Stream A has a child stream a and now, I would like to break child stream a from the integration stream A and I want stream a to be the child of stream B. Genetically, it might not be possible. But there might be a possibilty once you make both the integration srteam identical with same baseline. I would like to know if any of you have done in this kind of stuff in the past?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: no, you cannnot just "move" a stream from one parent to another.

The problem is: the foundation baselines of a child Stream only comes from the parent Stream.

That means a child from Stream B can only be rebased with baselines created on its parent.

If you want then to get a similar content, you would have to put baselines on stream_a (child of Stream A), and *deliver* those baselines onto the new stream.

That is quite cumbersome. I usually prefer to create a new project, with a new integration Stream which can use baselines from stream_a, and create new child streams from there.